# No Fill from server Failed to load add 3 Android adMob Using SDKBox

Tags: android, eclipse, admob, cocos2d-x

I have implemented AdMob using SDKBox for the cocos2d-x android project as well as the iOS project the same implementation works fine for iOS but on android, it is throwing an error that No Fill from the server. Failed to load the ad.
Error code 3.
Any help is appreciated Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error code say that the ad server cant supply an ad for your request [Reference](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest#ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL)

Ad fill depends on several parameters, main ones are Geo location of the user, device model and app content rating...

From what country are you making the request? try to use a proxy and request an ad as a US user, admob supply close to 100% for US users